# How to enable the server-side encryption with customer-managed keys stored in Managed HSM for managed disks?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-keyvault

I have created and activated Managed HSM using the following terraform script:

**main.tf**

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

## Create a Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}

## Create a Key Vault Managed Hardware Security Module
resource "azurerm_key_vault_managed_hardware_security_module" "kv_hsm" {
  name                       = var.kv_hsm_name
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  sku_name                   = var.sku_name
  purge_protection_enabled   = true
  soft_delete_retention_days = 90
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  admin_object_ids           = [data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id]
  tags                       = var.tags

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.resource_group
  ]
}

## Use openssl to generate 3 self signed certificate
resource "null_resource" "OPENSSLCERT" {
  count = 3
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
     cd  "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin"
    ./openssl.exe req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout ${var.KeyName[count.index]}  -x509 -days 365 -out ${var.CertName[count.index]} -subj "/C=IN/ST=XX/L=XX/O=abc ltd/OU=Stack/CN=abc.com"
    EOT
    interpreter = [
      "PowerShell", "-Command"
    ]
  }
}

## Use the az keyvault security-domain download command to download the security domain and activate your managed HSM.
resource "null_resource" "securityDomain" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
    az keyvault security-domain download --hsm-name ${azurerm_key_vault_managed_hardware_security_module.kv_hsm.name} --sd-wrapping-keys ./certs/cert_0.cer ./certs/cert_1.cer ./certs/cert_2.cer --sd-quorum 2 --security-domain-file ${azurerm_key_vault_managed_hardware_security_module.kv_hsm.name}-SD.json
    EOT
    interpreter = [
      "PowerShell", "-Command"
    ]
  }
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.OPENSSLCERT,
    azurerm_key_vault_managed_hardware_security_module.kv_hsm
  ]
}
```

I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-enable-customer-managed-keys-portal) documentation to enable the encryption using customer-managed keys stored in Managed HSM for managed disks. But while creating the Disk Encryption Set, I’m not able to see the Managed HSM created recently.

How to enable the server-side encryption with customer-managed keys stored in Managed HSM for managed disks using CLI/PowerShell/Portal?

Comment: Hello @pradeep, managed HSM cannot be seen from portal, you will have to use azure keyvault powershell module or azure keyvault cli module to make it work ..

Comment: let me create the same in my environment and get back here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments , you ***cannot find the HSM Key Vault in Portal*** , so you will have to ***use [`Azure Keyvault Powershell Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/?view=azurermps-6.13.0) or [`Azure Keyvault CLI Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault?view=azure-cli-latest)*** .

As a solution , You can add the below in your Terraform script to ***create a Disk Encryption Set with Managed HSM***:

```
resource "null_resource" "diskencryptionset" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
    $rgName='${azurerm_resource_group.example.name}'
    $location='${azurerm_resource_group.example.location}'
    $keyVaultName='${azurerm_key_vault_managed_hardware_security_module.example.name}'
    $keyName='diskencrytptionkey'
    $diskEncryptionSetName='ansumandiskset'
    az keyvault role assignment create --hsm-name $KeyvaultName --role "Managed HSM Crypto User" --assignee ${data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id} --scope /
    az keyvault key create --hsm-name $keyVaultName --name $keyName --protection software
    $keyVaultKeyUrl=$(az keyvault key show --hsm-name $keyVaultName --name $keyName --query [key.kid] -o tsv)
    az disk-encryption-set create -n $diskEncryptionSetName -l $location -g $rgName --source-vault $keyVaultName --key-url $keyVaultKeyUrl --enable-auto-key-rotation false
    $desIdentity=$(az disk-encryption-set show -n $diskEncryptionSetName -g $rgName --query [identity.principalId] -o tsv)
    az keyvault role assignment create --hsm-name $keyVaultName --role "Managed HSM Crypto Service Encryption User" --assignee $desIdentity --scope /keys
    EOT
    interpreter = [
      "PowerShell","-Command"
    ]
  }
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.securityDomain
  ]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]